# Need to check parameter against table rows in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to build one sql query in that one of my filed of form should not contain common names (maintained list of words in separate table) and i am passing value of that filed as parameter and want to check that it shouldn't contain any common name from that table.

How can i achieve that using sql query?

**Note :** if common name is 'abc' and i am passing parameter as '!abc123' since it contains that word query should return false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT word FROM CommonWord WHERE @yourparam 
                 LIKE '%' + word + '%')
    BEGIN
       RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      Return 0
    END
```

This works if the `@yourParam` is contained in any word or name, what you do not want to use. It only returns 1 if it is not contained by any row in the table.

*I worte this sentence only on this way (you can use a simple Exists instead of NOT Exists), because may you want to extend the functionality in the true part.*

Answer (score 3):

Try something like (Untested Query):

```
SELECT CommonName 
FROM CommonNamesTable 
WHERE CommonName like '%NameToTest%' 
OR CONTAINS(NameToTest, CommonName);
```

Basically you need the string match options:

Take a look at options of [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and read about [Queries with full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) == 0) FROM tablewithcommonwords 
WHERE wordfromform LIKE CONCAT('%', wordcolumnnfromcommonwordstable, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select * from reservedwords where @parameter like '%'+word + '%')
    select 0 
else
    select 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that You have to use keypress Event in Your TextBox and then Handle your Code after Each character enter in your TextBox.